# How to configure apache to run php code

Tags: apache, file, xampp

I have installed xampp in my D: . I have typed this in my apache/httpd.conf file :

```
#LoadModule php5_module "D:/xampp/php/php5apache2_2.dll" 

#AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 

#PHPIniDir "D:/xampp/php"
```

I have saved the file and restarted the apache server in the XAMPP CONTROL , but it still doesn't visualize php files on the browser.

Comment: You'll at least have to remove the `#` characters (since they comment out the rest of the line).

Comment: When I remove the # ,the apache server from the XAMPP control panel don't start.

Comment: Then you need to go look in the error log to see why it didn't start...

Comment: there is no errors in the error log file